# Wordpress image resize, no select input in mediagallery

Tags: image, wordpress, image-resizing

I use latest wp and there is my problem. For some images uploaded via mediagallery there is no select for changing img size.
But if i download it from my blog and upload it again, the select will be.
I cant understand, why this problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in server memory limit.
I used cache plugin to minimize wordpress memory usage and after that resizing problem was gone.
I also used plugin "resize thumbnails" to repair images with no size variations.